# Одновременный ввод данных в поле бд

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

Допустим, в web-приложении есть элемент `textarea`, в который вводится текст, по нажатию на клавишу `отправить` текст передается в базу данных (MSSQL). К `textarea` имеют доступ несколько пользователей, каждый может править уже существующий текст и вносить изменения в него. Если пользователи одновременно откроют страницу, и введут изменения (правки) в `textarea`, то в базе окажутся данные пользователя который отправит данные последним.

Как можно решить данную проблему?

Можно ли как-то отслеживать, что кто-то вводит данные в `textarea` и сообщать об этом другим пользователям.

Может есть другие варианты?

P.S. Приложение пишется на asp.net core 2.0.

Comment: При изменении textarea отправляй Ajax запрос на сервер и сравнивай с последним временем редактирования другого пользования.

Comment: А тут нет проблемы. В смысле программной. Это проблема организационная. *Можно ли как-то отслеживать, что кто-то вводит данные в textarea и сообщать об этом другим пользователям.* Ну... можно... при поддержке со стороны клиента как минимум. Хотя более разумно просто сверять исходное с исправленным перед записью и сообщать, что исходник уже поменялся. И пусть оператор принимает решение - а это опять организационный уровень.

Comment: Можно через websocket рассылать уведомление что текст редактируется у другого пользователя.

Answer (score 0):

Храните версию документа (номер с инкрементом или хэш), сравнивайте его в момент сохранения.

Если документ небольшой, передавайте и старую версию в момент сохранения тоже, и сравнивайте её.

Блокируйте документ от изменения (монопольный захват на какое-то время).

Рассылайте с бэкэнда через вебсокет уведомления об открытии документа всем заинтересованным лицам.

Или сделайте одновременное редактирование как например тут ["Совместное редактирование. Часть 1"](https://habrahabr.ru/company/ncloudtech/blog/264923/)